# Problema de Iteración en codigo de Media móvil exponencial

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, bucles, filtro

Muy buenas chicos. Resulta que llevo poco con Python y estoy escribiendo una clase que me calcula la media móvil exponencial de una serie de valores. El código es el siguiente:

```
class Mediamovilexponencial:
    def __init__(self, coeficiente):
        self.coeficiente = coeficiente
        self.filtrado = 0
        self.entrada = []

    def proceso(self, entrada):
        self.entrada = entrada
        self.filtrado += (self.entrada-self.filtrado)*self.coeficiente
        return self.filtrado
```

Pues resulta que en el proceso, quiero que con cada iteración  al dato filtrado anterior se le sume la operación entre paréntesis y se obtenga así el nuevo dato filtrado. Pero no ocurre así, es decir, 
en `self.filtrado` no se va guardando el resultado anterior de `self.filtrado`.

No consigo dilucidar cual podría ser el fallo en el código. Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: A `self.filtrado` en cada llamada al método `proceso` de una misma instancia se le asigna el valor de `self.filtrado + (self.entrada-self.filtrado)*self.coeficiente`, si no es así, algo más hay que no se refleja en el código mostrado. ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo de cómo instancias la clase, llamas a método y el resultado que obtienes y el que deberías obtener?

Answer (score 0):

El código parece correcto. Hay que tener en cuenta que el coeficiente decide que fracción (entre 0 y 1) la curva media va hacia cada entrada nueva. Si hay pocas entradas, una fracción más alta sigue las entradas más fiel.  Si hay muchas entradas, y las entradas en si no cambian mucho en cada paso, una fracción más pequeña puede ser más apropiado. Hay que experimentar un poco con los datos dependiendo de cada situación.

El código abajo muestra un ejemplo de aplicación con una fracción de `0.3`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random

class Mediamovilexponencial:
    def __init__(self, coeficiente):
        self.coeficiente = coeficiente
        self.filtrado = 0
        self.entrada = []

    def proceso(self, entrada):
        self.entrada = entrada
        self.filtrado += (self.entrada - self.filtrado) * self.coeficiente
        return self.filtrado

mediamovil = Mediamovilexponencial(0.3)
lista_entradas = []
lista_filtrada = []
entrada = 0
for _ in range(50):
    entrada += random.randint(-2, 3)
    lista_entradas.append(entrada)
    lista_filtrada.append(mediamovil.proceso(entrada))
plt.plot(lista_entradas, '.r-', label='Entradas')
plt.plot(lista_filtrada, 'b-', label='Filtrada')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: ejemplo]